# Unable to get redux state outside component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

My redux state of auth user looks like:

```
auth:{
    user: {
            created_at: "2021-05-12T06:08:57.000000Z"
            email: "johndoe@gmail.com"
            id: 1
            name: "John Doe"
            permissions: ["product-view", "product-create", "product-update", "product-destroy", "category-view",…]
            role: "superAdmin"
            role_id: 1
            updated_at: "2021-05-12T06:08:57.000000Z"
    }
}
```

And I am trying to check if user have permission or not using this permission array. For that I have created a utility file`authUser.js` and looks like:

```
import _ from "lodash";

import { store } from "../store";

let adminRole = ["superAdmin", "admin"];
const state = store.getState();
const currentUser = state.auth.user;

export async function havePermission(permission) {
    console.log("currentUser >>", currentUser);
    console.log("permission >>", permission);
    if (isAdmin()) {
        return true;
    }
    if (_.includes(currentUser.permissions, permission)) {
        return true;
    }
}

export async function isAdmin() {
    if (adminRole.includes(currentUser.role)) {
        return true;
    }
}

export default {
    isAdmin,
    havePermission,
};
```

and I am calling this function from 
**sidebar.jsx**

```
import authUser from "../../../utils/authUser";

const Sidebar = () => {
    return(

        <div>
            {console.log(` have permission called >>
                ${authUser.havePermission("product-view")}
            `)}
            {authUser.havePermission("view-name") &&
                "Dummy Name"}
        </div>

    )
}
```

and i am exporting store as `export { persistor, store };`

currently these data are showing up on console.log

```
currentUser >> {}
permission >> product-view
have permission called >> [object Promise]                      
currentUser >> {}
permission >> view-name
```

Unable to find, why currentUser is an empty object. How could I solve this permission check, as it currently it is returning empty object, although I can clearly see this user object on redux tab with values.

Comment: you may have some race conditions in here. `state.auth.user` already loaded before this runs, right? it's not loaded on page load? `isAdmin()` is async, but you're not waiting for that in `havePermission` so it's just hurdling through it. Also note how `have permission called` is an `[object Promise]`, from it being an async function and you're not waiting for it. I suggest cleaning these up first to rule out a race issue then see what you're left with

Comment: ah, I think I see it now, another race condition. you may want to try putting `const currentUser = state.auth.user` in the function `havePermission` as having it outside runs when the file is accessed, I believe, and will NOT rerun if the state changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your utility file, the call to `getState()` will only be called initially so whenever you try to access the `currentUser` you will have the default state without any updates that have been applied since.

```js
const state = store.getState();
const currentUser = state.auth.user;
```

You'll want to move the above call into a selector which will be given the current state and work out whether the current user has the permission, i.e.

```js
export async function havePermission(state, permission) {
    console.log("currentUser >>", state.auth.user);
    console.log("permission >>", state.auth.user.permissions);
    if (isAdmin(state.auth.user)) {
        return true;
    }
    if (_.includes(state.auth.user.permissions, permission)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

You can use the `useSelector` hook from `react-redux` which will pass through the current redux state, you can then pass this to `havePermission` to figure out whether the user has the specific permission.

```
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import {havePermission} from "../../../utils/authUser";

const Sidebar = () => {
    const hasProductPermission = useSelector((state) => havePermission(state, "product-view"));
    const hasViewNamePermission = useSelector((state) => havePermission(state, "view-name"));

    return(

        <div>
            {console.log(` have permission called >>
                ${hasProductPermission}
            `)}
            {hasViewNamePermission &&
                "Dummy Name"}
        </div>

    )
}
```

Additionally, you could move the `useSelector` call into a custom permissions hook:

```js
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { havePermission } from "../../../utils/authUser";

const usePermission = (permission) => {
   return useSelector((state) => havePermission(state, permission);
}
```

```js
const Sidebar = () => {
    const hasProductPermission = usePermission("product-view");
}
```

Comment: Thank you ljbc for the great explanation.

Comment: No worries, have a nice weekend :)